# NSRect coordinates of links in a WebView

Tags: cocoa, webview, screen, coordinates

I'm trying to find a way to get screen/NSRect coordinates of links in a WebView. I would like to do it with NSView but I can not find any way to the webView. One way that is possible is to use Javascript from Objective C via WebView but that looks to be complicated.

What are my options here?

The reason I'm trying to do this is I want to take a image of a webpage with WebView and create a html link-map for the links on the image.

Answer (score 2):

This works almost perfectly. Some links are out of place in the final image but I think that might be a DOM issue?

```
- (NSString *)constructLinkMap
{
    NSMutableString *result = nil;
    int i = 0;
    int linksCount = 0;

    result = [NSMutableString string];
    linksCount = [[[[webView mainFrame] DOMDocument] getElementsByTagName:@"a"] length];

    [result appendString:@"<map name=\"linkmap\">"];

    for (i = 0; i < linksCount; i++) {

        id linkItem = [[[[webView mainFrame] DOMDocument] getElementsByTagName:@"a"] item:i];

        if (([linkItem text] && ([[linkItem text] length] > 0)) && ([linkItem href] && ([[linkItem href] length] > 0))) {

            DOMRange *domRange = [webView selectedDOMRange];
            [domRange selectNode:linkItem];
            NSRect box = [linkItem boundingBox];

            if ((box.size.width > 0) && (box.size.height > 0))
                [result appendFormat:@"<area class=\"map\" shape=\"rect\" coords=\"%2.0f,%2.0f,%2.0f,%2.0f\" href=\"%@\" alt=\"%@\" />", box.origin.x, box.origin.y, (box.origin.x + box.size.width), (box.size.height + box.origin.y), [linkItem href], [linkItem text]];

            }
    }
    [result appendString:@"</map>"];

    return result;
}
```